# to_date function AM PM Format

Tags: sql, plsql

Reading from a csv file using perl and inserting into a oracle table.  In a particular csv field the date can be either in AM or PM format. So when i construct  the to_date I am using AM / PM but it's giving me format code error.    What formatcode needs to be provided in to_date to accept AM/PM Fields.

```
insert into invoices(invoice_id,invoice_date) values (2,to_date('2010-Aug-09 12:00:01 PM' , 'yyyy-Mon-dd HH:MI:SS AM / PM'));
```

Comment: Just as `yyyy` stands for "any four digit year" and `MI` stands for "any two-digit month", `AM` stands for "either AM or PM". You don't need to supply both possibilities in the format string.

Comment: MI is minutes, not month

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Oracle to\_date with p.m./a.m](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269903/oracle-to-date-with-p-m-a-m)

Answer (score 14):

You can specify either **[AM or PM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#i34924)**. Try

```
SELECT to_date('2010-Aug-09 02:00:01 PM' , 'yyyy-Mon-dd HH:MI:SS AM') "date"
  FROM dual;
SELECT to_date('2010-Aug-09 03:00:01 AM' , 'yyyy-Mon-dd HH:MI:SS PM') "date"
  FROM dual;
```

Output:

```
|                          DATE |
---------------------------------
| August, 09 2010 14:00:01+0000 |

|                          DATE |
---------------------------------
| August, 09 2010 03:00:01+0000 |
```

Here **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/12005)** demo